# What is the best way to display xml information on a web page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, web-services

I've currently got a service that produces xml files every 10 seconds containing server information. I'm looking for a way to display this on a web page.

I have been looking on the web for the best way to do this and it seems that using AJAX would be good as it allows the loading of dynamic content to be done in the background.

However how can i use AJAX? Should i add a ASP.NET website to my visual studio project? OR should i look to use javascript & AJAX in something like dreamweaver?

I'm very new to programming so i only really have a bit of experience in vb.net.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an ASP.NET page and use the built-in [AJAX ScriptManager and UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163354.aspx) controls.  They are very easy to incorporate.

Also, you don't want to bombard people with Raw XML, so [learn to use XSLT](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTutorial/Books/Book1/index.html).  I would suggest rendering it on the server using the [XSLCompiledTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0610k0w4.aspx).  Do this on the server, as you can mix and match the ASP.NET controls and HTML server controls.  I would suggest creating a `<div runat="server">`, place this in the **UpdatePanel**, and render XML via XSLT to this.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a .net developer so i don't know nothing about .net controls. But maybe you should take a look into jQuery and its ajax capabilities.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/